# typeahead from Bootstrap v2.2.1 skips every other value on key up or down in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm not sure if it's a new bug was introduced to TB or it's me, but it works in Chrome and IE, but doe NOT work in Firefox.

typeahead skips every other value on key up or down when suggestions are shown.

```
<input type="text" class="manufacturer typeahead" placeholder="manufacturer">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.manufacturer.typeahead').typeahead({
            "source":['manufacturer 1','manufacturer 2','manufacturer 3', 'manufacturer 4','manufacturer 5','manufacturer 6','manufacturer 7','manufacturer 8'],
            "items":8
        })
<script>
```

Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.1
jQuery 1.8.3
Firefox 16.0.2

Opened the bug anyway: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5943

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/gpfK8/3/) (start typing 'm')
or
[Official typeahead demo at TB site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) (start typing 'a')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really was a bug. Here is the fix:

```
    , move: function (e) {
    if (!this.shown) return

    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 9: // tab
        case 13: // enter
        case 27: // escape
            e.preventDefault()
            break

        case 38: // up arrow
            e.preventDefault()
            if (e.type=='keydown') this.prev()
            break

        case 40: // down arrow
            e.preventDefault()
            if (e.type=='keydown') this.next()
            break
    }
```

Comment: Late to the party - but I'm seeing this also.  Where would I want to add that "move" option, and is this fixed in newer versions of bootstrap?

Comment: @NeilM. I think [this was fixed long time ago](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5943).