# Bootstrap Typeahead keyboard not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I recently set up a Typeahaed in via Bootstrap and the keyboard (tab, arrow up, arrow down) is not working in Chrome. It's working in IE, Firefox, and Safari thought.

Here's the demo: http://cruiseoutlook.com/test

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Adelaide, Australia", "Agadir, Morocco", "Airlie Beach, Australia", "Ajaccio, Corsica", "Akaroa, New Zealand", "Alanya, Turkey", "Albany, Australia", "Alesund, Norway", "Alexandria, Egypt", "Alicante, Spain", "Almeria, Spain", "Amsterdam, Netherlands", "Anchorage, Alaska", "Antalya, Turkey", "Antigua, Island", "Aqaba, Jordan", "Argostoli, Greece", "Arica, Chile", "Arrecife, Canary Islands", "Aruba, Island", "Ashdod, Israel", "Astoria, Oregon", "At Sea, Sea", "Athens, Greece", "Auckland, New Zealand", "Baie Comeau, Canada", "Bali, Indonesia", "Baltimore, Maryland", "Bandar Seri Begawan, Brunei", "Bangkok (Laem Chabang), Thailand", "Bar Harbor, Maine", "Barbados, Island", "Barcelona, Spain", "Bari, Italy", "Bay of Islands, New Zealand", "Bayonne, New Jersey", "Beijing (Tianjin), China", "Belize, Belize", "Bergen, Norway", "Berlin, Germany", "Bilbao, Spain", "Boca da Valeria, Brazil", "Bodrum, Turkey", "Bombay, India", "Bonaire, Island", "Bora Bora, French Polynesia", "Bordeaux, France", "Boston, Massachusetts", "Bridgetown, Barbados", "Brindisi, Italy", "Brisbane, Australia", "Brugge, Belgium", "Buenos Aires, Argentina", "Burnie, Australia", "Busan, South Korea", "Busan, South Korea", "Busan, South Korea", "Buzios, Brazil", "Cabo Frio, Brazil", "Cabo San Lucas, Mexico", "Cadiz, Spain", "Cagliari, Italy", "Cairns, Australia", "Cairo, Egypt", "Cancun, Mexico", "Cannes, France", "Cape Horn, Chile", "Cartagena, Spain", "Cartagena, Colombia", "Casablanca, Morocco", "Castaway Cay, Bahamas", "Castries, Saint Lucia", "Catalina Island, California", "Catania, Italy", "Cephalonia, Greece", "Champagne Bay, Vanuatu", "Charleston, South Carolina", "Charlottetown, Prince Edward Island", "Chennai, India", "Cherbourg, France", "Cochin, India", "Colombo, Sri Lanka", "Colon, Panama", "Como, Italy", "Constanta, Romania", "Copenhagen, Denmark", "Corfu, Greece", "Corinto, Nicaragua", "Corner Brook, Newfoundland", "Costa Maya, Mexico", "Cozumel, Mexico", "Crete, Greece", "Curacao, Island", "Da Nang, Vietnam", "Darwin, Australia", "Delphi, Greece", "Devils Island (Isle Royale), French Guiana", "Dravuni Island, Fiji", "Dubai, United Arab Emirates", "Dubai, United Arab Emirates", "Dublin, Ireland", "Dubrovnik, Croatia", "Dunedin, New Zealand", "Easo (Lifou), New Caledonia", "Ensenada, Mexico", "Ephesus, Turkey", "Esperance, Australia", "Falmouth, Jamaica", "Fiordland National Park, New Zealand", "Florence, Italy", "Fort Lauderdale, Florida", "Fort-De-France, Martinique", "Freeport (Grand Bahama Island), Bahamas", "Fuerte Amador, Panama", "Fuerteventura, Canary Islands", "Galle, Sri Lanka", "Gallipoli, Italy", "Galveston, Texas", "Gaspe, Canada", "Genoa, Italy", "Gibraltar, England", "Gijon, Spain", "Glasgow, Scotland", "Gloucester, Massachusetts", "Gran Canaria, Spain", "Gran Canaria, Canary Islands", "Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands", "Grand Turk, Turks and Caicos", "Grenada, Island", "Guadeloupe, Island", "Gustavia, St. Barts", "Gythion, Greece", "Haifa, Israel", "Hainan, China", "Haines, Alaska", "Half Moon Cay, Bahamas", "Halifax, Nova Scotia", "Halong Bay, Vietnam", "Hamilton, Bermuda", "Hamilton Island, Australia", "Helsinki, Finland", "Hilo, Hawaii", "Ho Chi Minh City (Phu My), Vietnam", "Hobart, Tasmania", "Hong Kong, China", "Honolulu, Hawaii", "Horta, Portugal", "Huahine, French Polynesia", "Huatulco, Mexico", "Hubbard Glacier, Sea", "Ibiza, Spain", "Icy Strait Point, Alaska", "Ilha Grande, Brazil", "Ilhabela, Brazil", "Ilheus, Brazil", "Inside Passage, Sea", "Iraklion, Greece", "Isla Roatan, Honduras", "Isle of Pines, New Caledonia", "Istanbul, Turkey", "Ixtapa, Mexico", "Jacksonville, Florida", "Jerusalem, Israel", "Juneau, Alaska", "Kailua Kona, Hawaii", "Kangaroo Island, Australia", "Katakolon, Greece", "Kauai, Hawaii", "Ketchikan, Alaska", "Key West, Florida", "Kings Wharf, Bermuda", "Kingstown, Saint Vincent", "Ko Samui, Thailand", "Kochi, India", "Koper, Slovenia", "Korcula, Croatia", "Kotor, Montenegro", "Kuala Lumpur (Port Klang), Malaysia", "Kyoto, Japan", "La Baie, Canada", "La Coruna, Spain", "La Gomera, Canary Islands", "La Romana, Dominican Republic", "La Serena, Chile", "Labadee, Haiti", "Lahaina, Hawaii", "Langkawi, Malaysia", "Lanzarote, Canary Islands", "Las Palmas, Canary Islands", "Lerwick, Scotland", "Lima, Peru", "Limassol, Cyprus", "Limon, Costa Rica", "Lisbon, Portugal", "London, England", "Los Angeles, California", "Los Cristianos, Canary Islands", "Luganville, Vanuatu", "Mackay, Australia", "Madeira, Portugal", "Mahogany Bay, Honduras", "Malacca, Malaysia", "Malaga, Spain", "Male, Maldives", "Manaus, Brazil", "Manta, Ecuador", "Marmaris, Turkey", "Maui, Hawaii", "Melbourne, Australia", "Messina, Italy", "Miami, Florida", "Mindelo, Cape Verde", "Miyazaki, Japan", "Monte Carlo, Monaco", "Montego Bay, Jamaica", "Monterey, California", "Montevideo, Uruguay", "Montreal, Quebec", "Montreal, Quebec", "Moorea, French Polynesia", "Mormugao, India", "Muscat, Oman", "Mykonos, Greece", "Mystery Island (Aneityum), Vanuatu", "Nadi (Port Denarau), Fiji", "Nafplion, Greece", "Nagasaki, Japan", "Nanaimo, British Columbia", "Nanaimo, British Colombia", "Napier, New Zealand", "Naples, Italy", "Nassau, Bahamas", "Natal, Brazil", "Nessebar, Bulgaria", "New Orleans, Louisiana", "New York, New York", "Newcastle, Australia", "Newport, Rhode Island", "Nha Trang, Vietnam", "Nice, France", "Norfolk, Virginia", "Noumea, New Caledonia", "Ocho Rios, Jamaica", "Odessa, Ukraine", "Oranjestad, Aruba", "Orlando, Florida", "Oslo, Norway", "Pago Pago, American Samoa", "Palma de Mallorca, Spain", "Panama Canal, Sea", "Panama City, Panama", "Parati, Brazil", "Parintins, Brazil", "Paris, France", "Patmos, Greece", "Penang, Malaysia", "Perth, Australia", "Phuket, Thailand", "Picton, New Zealand", "Ponta Delgada, Azores", "Port Blair, India", "Port Canaveral, Florida", "Port Douglas, Australia", "Port Elizabeth, Saint Vincent", "Port Lincoln, Australia", "Port of Spain, Trinidad", "Port Said, Egypt", "Portimao, Portugal", "Portland, Maine", "Porto, Portugal", "Porto Belo, Brazil", "Portofino, Italy", "Princess Cays, Bahamas", "Progreso, Mexico", "Provence, France", "Puerto Caldera (Puntarenas), Costa Rica", "Puerto Chacabuco, Chile", "Puerto Chiapas, Mexico", "Puerto Limon, Costa Rica", "Puerto Madryn, Argentina", "Puerto Montt, Chile", "Puerto Quetzal, Guatemala", "Puerto Vallarta, Mexico", "Punta Arenas, Chile", "Punta Del Este, Uruguay", "Puntarenas, Costa Rica", "Quebec City, Quebec", "Raiatea, French Polynesia", "Rangiroa, French Polynesia", "Ravenna, Italy", "Recife, Brazil", "Reykjavik, Iceland", "Rhodes, Greece", "Rio De Janeiro, Brazil", "Rome, Italy", "Roseau, Dominica", "Rotterdam, Netherlands", "Safaga, Egypt", "Saguenay, Canada", "Saint Croix, Virgin Islands", "Saint John, New Brunswick", "Saint John, Virgin Islands", "Saint Kitts, Island", "Saint Lucia, Island", "Saint Maarten, NA", "Saint Petersburg, Russia", "Saint Pierre, Miquelon", "Saint Thomas, Virgin Islands", "Salvador, Brazil", "Samana, Dominican Republic", "San Blas Islands, Panama", "San Diego, California", "San Francisco, California", "San Juan, Puerto Rico", "San Juan del Sur, Nicaragua", "Santa Barbara, California", "Santa Margherita, Italy", "Santa Marta, Colombia", "Santarem, Brazil", "Santiago, Chile", "Santo Tomas, Guatemala", "Santorini, Greece", "Sao Paulo, Brazil", "Sardinia, Italy", "Sardinia, Italy", "Savusavu, Fiji", "Scarborough, Trinidad and Tobago", "Seattle, Washington", "Sevastopol, Ukraine", "Seville, Spain", "Shanghai, China", "Sicily, Italy", "Sihanoukville, Cambodia", "Singapore, Singapore", "Sinop, Turkey", "Sitka, Alaska", "Skagway, Alaska", "Sochi, Russia", "Sorrento, Italy", "Sousse, Tunisia", "Southampton, England", "Split, Croatia", "Stanley, Falkland Islands", "Stirrup Cay (CocoCay), Bahamas", "Stockholm, Sweden", "Suva, Fiji", "Sydney, Nova Scotia", "Sydney, Australia", "Tahiti, French Polynesia", "Tallinn, Estonia", "Tampa, Florida", "Tangier, Morocco", "Tauranga, New Zealand", "Tenerife, Canary Islands", "Thorshavn, Faroe Islands", "Tokyo, Japan", "Tortola, British Virgin Islands", "Townsville, Australia", "Trabzon, Turkey", "Trapani, Italy", "Trieste, Italy", "Trujillo, Peru", "Tunis, Tunisia", "Ushuaia, Argentina", "Valencia, Spain", "Valletta, Malta", "Valparaiso, Chile", "Vancouver, British Columbia", "Varna, Bulgaria", "Venice, Italy", "Victoria, British Colombia", "Victoria, Malta", "Vigo, Spain", "Vila, Vanuatu", "Vladivostok, Russia", "Volos, Greece", "Wellington, New Zealand", "Yalta, Ukraine", "Yangon, Myanmar"]'>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/XUdEZ/

Comment: even like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XUdEZ/2/ (with all your html, except the css and js file - they are loaded as "resources")

Comment: Thanks for the helps Alex! Looks like I need to check my css & js files

Comment: The thing is that all css are taken from your site (you can click on the `Manage Resources` in the second jsfiddle) The only thing different is the jQuery library.

Comment: Also note, that there is a bug with typeahead 2.2.1 in FireFox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446534/typeahead-from-bootstrap-v2-2-1-skips-every-other-value-on-key-up-or-down-in-fir/13473607#13473607

Comment: It was as simple as changing the jQuery version from 1.8.0 to 1.8.2 - would have never guess that one without your help - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, jQuery 1.8.0 has an issue that causes typeahead to misbehave in Chrome. (However I cannot find that change in either [1.8.1 changelog](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/) and [1.8.2 changelog](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/09/20/jquery-1-8-2-released/))